# Is it possible to change the parameters of onCreate() in a fragment

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the parameters of onCreate() in a fragment (If We can Then will it be called in the beginning similar to a normal onCreate() Method.

Comment: how could Android be aware of your custom params ?

Comment: There is an @Override annotation right above that method, get started with some basics first.

Comment: No, this is not possible. onCreate method is the override method. The Fragment class contains the definition of this method. If you don't override that and write your own, it'll not be called until you call it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

NO You can't change its parameters.